# How to load image from picasso to subsampling-scale-image-view..please can any one simplify this?

Tags: java, android, picasso

I want to load the image from URL through picasso library to subsampling-scale-image-view in android studio.

I had tried the picasso decoder and picasso region decoder but it gives error on okhttp3downloader client constructor.

```
public class PicassoRegionDecoder implements ImageRegionDecoder {

    private OkHttpClient client;
    private BitmapRegionDecoder decoder;
    private final Object decoderLock = new Object();

    public PicassoRegionDecoder (OkHttpClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public Point init(Context context, Uri uri) throws Exception {

        OkHttp3Downloader downloader=new OkHttp3Downloader(client);
        //OkHttpDownloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(client);
        InputStream inputStream = downloader.load(uri, 0).getInputStream();
        this.decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(inputStream, false);

        return new Point(this.decoder.getWidth(), this.decoder.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap decodeRegion(Rect rect, int sampleSize) {
        synchronized(this.decoderLock) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            Bitmap bitmap = this.decoder.decodeRegion(rect, options);
            if(bitmap == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Region decoder returned null bitmap - image format may not be supported");
            } else {
                return bitmap;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReady() {
        return this.decoder != null && !this.decoder.isRecycled();
    }

    @Override
    public void recycle() {
        this.decoder.recycle();
    }
}
```

> cannot resolve constructor OkHttpDownloader(client)

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

Subsampling scale image view is an "old" post.

You have to be careful of the imports, these were working :

```
implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
```

Now, if you would like to use recent libraries, change your code snippet to :

```
@Override
public Point init(Context context, Uri uri) throws Exception {
    OkHttp3Downloader downloader = new OkHttp3Downloader(client);
    okhttp3.Request request = new Request.Builder().url(uri.toString()).build();
    InputStream inputStream = downloader.load(request).body().byteStream();
    this.decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(inputStream, false);

    return new Point(this.decoder.getWidth(), this.decoder.getHeight());
}
```

**PLEASE REFER TO DAVEMORRISSEY'S (the dev) POST HERE**

https://gist.github.com/davemorrissey/e2781ba5b966c9e95539

and read the comments